# How to store two Integers in one Django model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Inside my Django model which is called Setup, I have an instance dedicated to the timing that the user can set in case of fast operation.
 
In real life, the timing is expressed by two numbers, example: 
timing: 5-10 seconds
where 5 is the "pause" and 10 the "motor on" time.
 
Now, I know that probably the best way to have this set up is to separate the two and have one instance for each, but for usability reason I'd need to keep the "real" format, so number + hyphen + number.
**Is there any way in Django to store two different numbers in the same model instance?**
There will be a form for this model and ideally it should have input + hyphen + input.

fast_op_timing = models.IntegerField...??

Thank you very much in advance. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Then it is a `CharField` (so stored as text, but *yuck*, don't store it as text), use two integers. It is more semantical to reality, and allows to easily filter on the two subparts (independently).

Comment: If you use Postgres check out the JSONField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two integer fields will give sort your numerical needs and overriding the `str` function will give you the usabillity you are looking for.

```
class Setup(models.Model):
    pause = models.IntegerField()
    motor = models.IntegerField()

    def user_view(self):
        return "{}-{} seconds".format(self.pause, self.motor)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.view()
```

**Example**

```
> my_setup = Setup(pause=5, motor=10)
> print(str(my_setup))
5-10
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll go with this option. Just one question: right now, my str function prints the name of the setup (with name being a model instance too, alongside pause and motor). How can I add the option of showing pause and motor properly formatted only in the model detail view? The detail view is the one where all the instances and their values are displayed on the page.  Thank you again!

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot about that. Check my updated code, i've added a method that should give you what you want I think?

Comment: I was able to test it and it seems to do exactly what I need! I can't thank you enough. (Pardon the late reply, I did not manage to test it sooner).

Comment: Ah no worries, happy to help. :)